# NodeJs / Express Get ID//name of submit button pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-submit

Is there a way to get the ID/name of the submit button that we press ?

I have a table with on each column a delete button . i want to get the name or the ID to know which row i need to delete

```
<form method="post" action="delete">
    <input type="submit" id="1" name="1" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" id="2" name="2" value="Delete">
</form>
```

when i say that i need the id or name , i want it server-side .

i tried something like this

```
app.post('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
```

but how can use :id as a variable to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `req.params.id`

Please refer http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

By the way, your action just says "delete" and it is a form POST with submit buttons. So it will not generate the URL you need, which is /delete/:id.

You will need to generate the URL dynamically using some client-side JS and click events.

Comment: So how can i get the ID of my submit button in Nodejs ?

Comment: One (rather simple and crude) way would be to append the ID to the form action and submit it when the button is clicked.
`<input ...value="Delete" onclick="document.forms[0].action+='/'+this.id;return true;">`

Comment: How do i catch the id in NodeJS then ?

Comment: Oh yes thanks didn't see , what do you mean with "document.forms[0]

Comment: I am accessing the first available form. This is not ideal, but as I said a crude way. Ideally you should be looking it up using form ID. Basically the idea, as I said, is to modify your form's action from just "delete" to "delete/<id>" where ID is only known on click.

Comment: But that's actually what i want , get the ID of the delete button i click (for each row in my table there is a delete button)

Comment: What if i replace the input type submit with a button , is this way easier or not ?

Comment: There are actually a lot of things to consider (AJAX/normal req, one form per row, etc etc), it is beyond the scope of SO comments. If you're just doing a small POC or sample app, the code I've given should suffice. Just add it to the button and on server side look up the value from req.params

Comment: Not working for me , the link after clicking the button don't show the ID .

Comment: That's odd. I tried it before posting and it worked. What's the exact URL to which the form gets submitted on click of the button?

Comment: Client-side : <form method="post" action="vehicules/delete" >
                                    <input type="submit" id="<%= CarList[i].IDVehicule %>" Value="Supprimer" onclick="document.forms[0].action+='/'+this.id;return true;">
                                    </form>
Server Side :  app.post('/vehicules/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});

Comment: Looks good, unless you have another form in your code. Can you tell me what happens on click of the button? Does the page refresh? What URL does it go to (check the address bar)? Anything printed on server side?

Comment: Have got other form , but far away from this piece of code , nothing happend in server side and that's the url before http://localhost:8080/vehicules and after http://localhost:8080/vehicules/delete

Comment: With the message "cannot post vehicules/delete" (sound's logic if the app.post is vehicules/delete/:id)

Comment: Right, so I think `forms[0]` is picking up that other form. Do one thing, add an ID to your delete form `<form id="mydelform" method= ....` and in the button onclick code I've provided, change `document.forms[0].action` to `document.getElementById('mydelform').action`

Comment: Working now, had an other problem , i had my form in my for loop xd , put it out and now it"s working  :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make a hidden input and before submit it write the value of id into this input. jQuery example:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'form > button', function(){
   jQuery('input[hidden]').val(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Even if you do this, it will not put the ID in the URL as path param.

Comment: With this solution i can catch the input value with req.body but how do i give a name/id to the hidden input ?

Comment: You must create a hidden input in form before. And in NodeJs you get this param in req.body.{name you hidden input}.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think the name value has same restriction as an element ID but I would use a more explicit name that doesn´t start with a number.

The standard way is to add the express [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) as a middlware and then the data will be available in the req.body.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the URL based on id or name, then i would suggest not to use form. Instead wrap all inputs inside in div or some other elements as you wish and give a common class only for that inputs to all the inputs as shown below.

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" class="myClass" id="1" name="1" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" class="myClass" id="2" name="2" value="Delete">
</div>
```

Then in jquery you can you do the following

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){
   var url= "/delete/" + this.id;
   $.post(url, function(data) {
       ....
   });
});
```